# Selectively mocking a function on Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I might be missing something major here, but I can't seem to find a suitable answer from the docs. I'm trying to selectively replace a utility function with a mock implementation in Jest. My reasoning for this is that sometimes I want to force it to fail during testing to see how it impacts the rest of my code, and also to see if my catches are working properly. For example

```
// actual.js
export const foo = () => {return 'foo'}

//mock.js
export const foo = (returnFoo) => {return returnFoo ? 'foo' : 'bar'}
```

I can't seem to use `jest.mock(actual.js)` because the 2 functions have different signatures. I can use `jest.setMock()` with `jest.requireActual()`, but it'll mock `foo` for the entire suite. My current solution is doing

```
const mock = jest.spyOn(actual, 'foo');
mock.mockImplementation(() => mock.foo(returnFoo));

which can be simplified to

jest.spyOn(actual, 'foo').mockImplementation(() => mock.foo(returnFoo));
```

which **does** works. I'm really just wondering if Jest has a better way of doing this than adding a spy on every individual function I want to purposely and manually mock for individual tests. I've also tried doing `const actual.foo = jest.fn()`, but that doesn't work since `foo` in `actual` is a read-only export, and also `Object.defineProperty(vendorsRepo, 'updateToken', { value: mockedVendorsRepo.updateToken() });` but that seems like a terrible workaround.

Comment: Usually `jest.mock('actual.js')` is the best way to go. Probably you should describe a bit better what exactly is the problem using it

Comment: I think I was pretty clear about my troubles with it. But I'll elaborate. The actual function and the mocked function has 2 different signatures. During my tests, if one of my functions call the utility function foo(), then it has no problems, but since the mock replaces the function, I can't selectively fail it by calling foo(false) during a test where foo is supposed to fail.

Comment: I'm also fairly certain using spies on function specifically for changing mock values is it's primary use, I'm just seeing if there's a shorthand way of doing it, that's all. :)